# Permission error when installing textblob

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, nltk

This command:

```
python -m pip install textblob
```

gave this error:

> error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk': Permission denied

and

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9z/kwrqy2qn49s1rt0zf5ft12h80000gn/T/pip-build-gyWGVB/nltk/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9z/kwrqy2qn49s1rt0zf5ft12h80000gn/T/pip-1Cek94-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9z/kwrqy2qn49s1rt0zf5ft12h80000gn/T/pip-build-gyWGVB/nltk/`

I'm using:

- OS X 10.11.6
- python version 2.7.10
- pip 8.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with permission.

```
sudo pip install textblob
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using sudo pip, because of it being potentially unsafe, but after doing some more research and your suggestions I guess there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the user you logged-in doesn't have appropriate permissions to do this, so do it with sudo or su

```
sudo pip install textblob
```

or you can first switch as root user and then fire the command:

```
su
pip install textblob
```